# node.js cannot set header error using res.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
if (user) {

    if (userId != user._id) {
        res.json({success: false, msg: 'Invalid request, wrong secret key'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
        if (result === true) {

            res.json({success: true, msg: 'ok'});
        } else {
            res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error, Incorrect password!'});
        }
    });
} else {
    res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Error, account not exist!'});
}
```

I thought the first res.json will stop the following res.json but in this case I seem can't use the first res.json, I don't know why.

Comment: `res.json()` does not stop code execution. You need to explicitly call `return` if you want it to  act as _short circuit_ statement, e.g.: `return res.json();`

Answer (score 0):

`res.json()` sends the response, but it does not prevent the rest of your code from running.

As such, you have some code paths that attempt to send `res.json()` twice which will cause the error message you are seeing.  You need to prevent that either with appropriate `if/then` blocks or by inserting appropriate `return` statements.

I'd suggest this:

```
if (user) {

    if (userId != user._id) {
        res.json({success: false, msg: 'Invalid request, wrong secret key'});
        return;
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
        if (result === true) {

            res.json({success: true, msg: 'ok'});
        } else {
            res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error, Incorrect password!'});
        }
    });
} else {
    res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Error, account not exist!'});
}
```

But, you also could fix it by adding an `else` to the first `if` and putting the rest of the code inside that.

Comment: return means I stop the code after my first res.json?

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler - Yes, `return` makes it so that it does not execute the rest of this code.  Once you've sent the response with `res.json()`, that response is done.  You can't send any more.  If you try to send more on that response, it causes an error. You could also add an `else` to the second `if` as another way to do it.

Comment: what if I do return false?

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler - You do not show what function this code is inside of so I have no idea what it does or doesn't do to use `return false`.  It depends entirely upon whether the caller of the function that this code is in is looking at the return value or not and what it is expecting.  You'd have to show us a lot more of your code for us to have any idea about that.